Projective representations that are compatible with a group automorphism
We know that projective representations of a group $G$, $\rho(g) \rho(h) = e^{i\omega(g,h)} \rho(gh)$, is classified by the second group cohomology $H^2(G,U(1))$. Let us now specify a group automorphism $A:G\rightarrow G$. I wonder what mathematical object classifies the projective representation of G subject to the constraint $e^{i \omega(g,h)}=e^{i \omega(A(g),A(h))}$?

I think you just need the cohomology class in $H^2$ to be fixed under the action of $A$.
